# RecycleView OnClickListener

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Have One RecycleView Adapted By Model Image & Text Custom Layout
Every thing is Ok just I need Click Item By **OnClickListener** Please Help Me

**FeedItem.java**

```
public class FeedItem {
private String title;
private String thumbnail;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}}
```

**FeedListRowHolder.java**

```
public class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
protected ImageView thumbnail;
protected TextView title;
Context context;

public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);


}}
```

**MyRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedListRowHolder> {
private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
private Context mContext;
public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
    this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    FeedListRowHolder mh = new FeedListRowHolder(v);

    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
    FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
            .error(R.drawable.list)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.info)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
}}
```

**Im Need Code**

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    CustomViewHolder holder = (CustomViewHolder) view.getTag();
    int position = holder.getPosition();

    FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, feedItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is you want???

```
  @Nullable
private OnItemClickListener listener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    if (null != listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onClick(FeedItem feedItem, int position);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
        .error(R.drawable.list)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.info)
        .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);
feedListRowHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                         if (listener != null) {
                            listener.onClick(item, position);
                        }
                    }
                });


}
```

Comment: Its better to add onClickListener in onCreateViewHolder method